# I Couldn't access to NTFS partition from Ubuntu OS

Tags: partition, dual-boot

this massage appear when I tried to access to this partition:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/ali/Ali: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda3" "/media/ali/Ali"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: And what is your question exactly? Did you proceed as written in the error message?

Comment: Also try disabling the Fast Startup feature in Windows, otherwise youĺl always have the same problem. Even better do not do that, do not access the Windows system partition from outside.

Answer (score 1):

The message said that your ntfs partition was not correctly shutdown.
So you must boot it(the partition) on windows,then close correctly windows
(shutdown),and then remount it on linux with option ro(readonly) or rw if you want to write to ntfs partition.

```
mount -o ro /dev/sda3 /whereyouwant
```